# Angular2 - How to use router with dynamic urls

Tags: angular

Suppose I have this nested itemListComponent, which is a child of a rootComponent, using the following template:

```
<span *ngFor="#item of list">
    <a [routerLink]="[item.url]">{{item.title}}</a> |
</span>
```

The path item.url, which is provided from a Json service, could have one of the following path structure:

- /category1/(a content id)/(a title connected with dashes(-))
- /category2/(a content id)/(a title connected with dashes(-))
- /category3/(a content id)/(a title connected with dashes(-))

Examples:

```
category2/987654/hello-world
category2/123456/hi-teacher
category3/554433/yo-brother
```

How could @RouteConfig be implemented so that these links use a itemDetail component?

Sorry if this does not look very detailed. I did not find a clear how-to-guide for routing urls that are provided by a service with full paths (not assembled paths)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
<span *ngFor="#item of list">
   <a [routerLink]="['/category', item.url]">
        {{item.title}}
   </a>
</span>
```

routes.ts:

```
{path: "category/:id", component: CategoryComponent}
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question. May be angular team has added this recently. Thanks!

Comment: @Ivan Pianetti what if we want to add more than two parameters in dynamic URL like <a [routerLink]="['/category', item.url, item.url1]">

Answer (score 3):

That's what [regex matches](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7332/commits/c45bfb21bcae22e06eec7650da1ca865973e424d) are for. But if you have pre-assembled URLs you may not want to use `routerLink` with them. RouterLink expects an array, you will have to use simple URLs.

Consider your original snippet

```
<span *ngFor="#item of list">
    <a [href]="item.url">{{item.title}}</a> |
</span>
```

Assuming you're using `HashLocationStrategy` your URL should contain the hash

```
<span *ngFor="#item of list">
    <a [href]="'#/' + item.url">{{item.title}}</a> |
</span>
```

That should result in an URL like this

```
#/category2/987654/hello-world
```

Now that we have the URLs correctly formed, we can use the regex matchers we mentioned earlier

```js
@RouteConfig([
  {
    name : 'ItemDetail',

    // regex that will match the URL in the href or the URL typed directly by the user
    regex : '^([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)$',

    // serializer is mandatory, but it is used when you have a routerLink with params
    serializer : (params) => {
      return new GeneratedUrl(`${params.a}/${params.b}/${params.c}`)
    },
    component : ItemDetail
  }
])
```

This is the easiest if you have pre-assembled URLs.

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJ88D7Ad1XYkliTuyw4Z?p=preview) with an example working.

Note that regex matchers were introduced in beta.9 and they contain a few issues, see

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7602
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7554
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7531

You may found other ones.

I really apologize for my bad regex skills, probably you can bypass it, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Comment: Many thanks Eric, It did the trick. However,  routerLink seems however necessary to use a PathLocationStrategy.

Comment: It is not possible to use regular expressions inside the angular 2 now..

Answer (score 0):

Although Eric's solution using regexes works fine using HashLocationStrategy, the solution I used is based on this [article](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/) and [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5IzUH0pc3nN1O7iQZkD?p=preview) by Yavo Fain.

I then converted to a PathLocationStrategy (using APP_BASE_HREF. See [official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/PathLocationStrategy-class.html))

To make the PathLocationStrategy work we need to make the index.html as the default fallback page on the server side. Here is an example using gulp-webserver:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() { 
    gulp.src('app') .pipe(webserver({ 
        fallback: 'index.html' 
    })); 
});
```

We need to use routerLink with a PathLocationStrategy. Otherwise the browser will refresh the page when routing to urls and it won't completely behave like a one-page app.

I could then use *ngFor loop to render different items with different paths and ids.

```
<div *ngFor="#item of list">
    <a [routerLink]="['ContentId', {id:item.url}]">{{item.title}}</a>
</div>
```