# Angular Routes not accepting json array routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**The problem**

So I am pretty new to Angular but picking up the pace quickly. I want Angular to be dynamic when it comes to its Routing functions. Thus I created a small api for Angular to contact returning an array. When I iterate over the array its contents are not applied when loading them into the Routing Module. But if i use the same method to load hardcoded routes it does work!

When I target the url: cms/bla or cms/dashboard it works but any other url isnt recognised. The [i]['path'] is a string. E.g. one of the strings being cms/login angular returns it as not found. Am I missing something here?

When I review the console it shows me: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}], when I open its contents all my routes are there including the hardcodes ones at the very bottom.

**Here is my code**

```
import { ApiResult } from './objects/api';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const routes: Routes = prepareRoutes();

function prepareRoutes() {
  const newRoutes: Routes = [{path: 'cms/bla', component: DashboardComponent}];
  newRoutes.unshift({path: 'bla', component : DashboardComponent});
  newRoutes.unshift({path: 'cms/dashboard', component : DashboardComponent});

  fetch(environment.apiUrl + '/routes/').then((value: Response)  => {
    return value.json();
    }).then((routeResults: ApiResult) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < routeResults.data.length; i++) {
      newRoutes.unshift({path: routeResults.data[i]['path'], component: DashboardComponent});
      }
    });
  return newRoutes;
}

console.log(routes);
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
import { ApiResult } from './objects/api';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router} from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const routes: Routes = [{path: 'cms/bla', component: DashboardComponent},
{path: 'bla', component : DashboardComponent},
{path: 'cms/dashboard', component : DashboardComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    fetch(environment.apiUrl + '/routes/').then((value: Response)  => {
    return value.json();
    }).then((routeResults: ApiResult) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < routeResults.data.length; i++) {
      router.config.unshift({path: routeResults.data[i]['path'], component: DashboardComponent});
      }
      console.log(router.config);
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: your return is called before the the response from api you've attached. This is how Js works

Answer (score 0):

As you are making an API request to fetch routes, which become asynchronous.
By the time API response come, you have returned the routes with hardcoded one only.

You can add your async routes in your AppComponent(or any other component) using "Router.config"

Do following in your AppComponent constructor.

```
    constructor(router: Router){
        fetch(environment.apiUrl + '/routes/').then((value: Response)  => {
        return value.json();
        }).then((routeResults: ApiResult) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < routeResults.data.length; i++) {
          this.router.config.unshift({path: routeResults.data[i]['path'], component: DashboardComponent});
          }
        });
     }
```

Comment: Hello Deshak9, I have followed your advise and updated my code a bit (UPDATE #1) I can now see that the items are being loaded but AFTER I have requested the url. I am using Angular's routing module (app-routing.module.ts). This one is used to redirect content with the <app-routing> node. How can I load the routes before this module is loaded?

Comment: I think that won't be possible, only one another way would be to use dynamic path, have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207023/angular2-how-to-use-router-with-dynamic-urls